# Using constants to define atributes for model objects using arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, object, constants

My question is the following. I accept that maybe using array than objects in PHP might be better for performance; like i read in many posts. But i work in an enviorment where the code are with a lot of lines of codes and a lot of array; the problem is that when i wanted to modify or study a code i dont know what variables the arrays have, for example:

```
$person['age'] = 18;
$person['name'] = 'Robert';
```

I don´t have the complete information if that variable person has other details; the solution is using the debugger for watch what other information holds the array $person.

I thought about trying to use clases (like models) to represent the objects. Like:

```
class Person {
    const AGE = 'age';
    const NAME = 'name';
}

$person[Person::AGE] = 18;
$person[Person::NAME] = 'Robert';
```

So i will know what attributes has Person.

The questions are: 
Its better using array than object? 
if i prefer using array: is there any way to improve the maintainability of the code using other class like the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make a person class?  Then you know the attributes that they will all have.

```
class Person {
    protected $age;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function getAge() { 
        return $this->age; 
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

This way if you wanted to add some type checking or formatting you can add it to this class rather than having to search everywhere in your codebase for where the key of the array is.

These data objects are fairly straight forward but you will be able to consolidate functionality very easily and it will be easier to maintain with knowing where they are.

If your arrays having the properties for person represent different objects, you would be able to leverage an abstract class so that you know that they have the property.  Or just an interface specifying that the class would have a `getAge` or `getName` method.

Specifying the keys of your array with class constants is really just a small step away from using objects.  Take that step.  You can also avoid having to worry about having to check if the key is valid in your arrays.  Your objects can set a default value for you and you can use the object with confidence as to what properties that it has.

Comment: @Schleis, thanks for your answer. I have a little concern about the performance of using always objects in the application, because is a very big application; and also there are many places using arrays in the way i wrote in the example; so i have to do two things:

1 - try to improve the way the are using the Array.
2 - explore if using objects intead of array in a big quantity, will not jeopardy the performance.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be an excuse for sloppy project. Using an object instead of array directly adds minimal overhead, if any. You use objects to ease **your** development, to lower development time and minimalize time spent to add/update/maintain the project. Also, don't falsely assume that object oriented approach kills the performance for some reason.

Comment: @N.B. So, you conclusion is trying to change using array to object? and for example if existis some resistence of that kind of changes: the approach i present of using constants is an no sense workaround?

Comment: Exactly, what you tried to do is half the step to object oriented way. Also, performance hit, IF ANY, is negligible. This answer correctly tells you that it's the right and the only sane way to go.

Comment: i think the same as you, just i wanted to know other opinion. Thanks for the answer.